# How to add exist share library to BlackBerry Native SDK project and deploy to Device or Simulator?

Tags: sdk, native, blackberry-playbook

I'm developing an app for BlackBerry Playboock using 
BlackBerry Native SDK. I want to know how to add a share lib for my app and deploy this lib to my device. I have found this [link](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/com.qnx.doc.native_sdk.devguide/com.qnx.doc.native_sdk.devguide/topic/t_wf_add_shared_libraries.html)! and [this](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/com.qnx.doc.native_sdk.devguide/com.qnx.doc.native_sdk.devguide/topic/t_wf_package_deploy_use_ide.html)! but I don't know how to do?
I'm new at this platform. Some body help me !